# Why the displacement between two endpoints of joint clothoid doesn't match to that from simulation?

Tags: matlab, calculation

I want to calculate the displacement of two endpoints in a joint clothoid, but the result is different from the simulation result. Where is the problem of my calculation?

[image of three clothoids](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApwLp.jpg)
[image]

I calculate separated clothoid' displacements, then rotate the coordination to do the superposition in value of points.

[the following shows the parameters of each clothoids](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoQpt.jpg)
[image]

````
The following is the code to do coordinate calculation and conversion for three clothoid

    ```m 

    arcLengthClothoid1= 62.65;
    arcLengthClothoid2= 64.38;
    arcLengthClothoid3= 94.24; 
    % delta_X= solve(polyint(cos(x.^2/(2*R*L))));
    % delta_Y= solve(polyint(sin(x.^2/(2*R*L))));

    %%First clothoid
    fun1= @(x)cos(x.^2/(2*304*arcLengthClothoid1));
    delta_x1= integral(fun1,0,arcLengthClothoid1);
    fun2= @(x)sin(x.^2/(2*304*arcLengthClothoid1));
    delta_y1= integral(fun2,0,arcLengthClothoid1);
    angle1= (arcLengthClothoid1^2/2/(304*arcLengthClothoid1))/pi;

    %%Second clothoid
    fun3= @(x)cos(x.^2/(2*304*489.85));
    delta_x2= integral(fun3,425.3357,489.7157);
    fun4= @(x)sin(x.^2/(2*304*489.7157));
    delta_y2= integral(fun4,425.3357,489.7157);
    angle1= (arcLengthClothoid1^2/2/(304*arcLengthClothoid1))/pi;

    %
    angle22=  (489.7157^2/2/(1.4887e+05))/pi ;
    angle21=  (425.3357^2/2/(1.4887e+05))/pi ;
    angle2= angle22- angle21;
    angle2= angle1- (1*arcLengthClothoid2^2/2/(350*arcLengthClothoid2))/pi ;
    %coordinate correction
    end_point2= [delta_x2, delta_y2];
    c_end_point2= end_point2 * [cos(angle1), -sin(angle1)
                                sin(angle1), cos(angle1)];
    %%Third clothoid
    fun5= @(x)cos(x.^2/(2*350*arcLengthClothoid3));
    delta_x3= integral(fun5,0,arcLengthClothoid3);
    fun6= @(x)sin(x.^2/(2*350*arcLengthClothoid3));
    delta_y3= integral(fun6,0,arcLengthClothoid3);
    %coordinate correction
    end_point3= [delta_x3, delta_y3];
    c_end_point3= end_point3 * [cos(angle1- angle2), -sin(angle1- angle2)
                                sin(angle1- angle2), cos(angle1- angle2)];
    %angle3= angle2 -(1*arcLengthClothoid3^2/2/(350*arcLengthClothoid3))/pi;
    angle3=(1*arcLengthClothoid3^2/2/(350*arcLengthClothoid3))/pi;

    delta_x= delta_x1+ c_end_point2(1,1)+ c_end_point3(1,1);
    delta_y= delta_y1- c_end_point2(1,2)- c_end_point3(1,2);
    delta_angle= angle1- angle2- angle3;
````

[However, the C1's result is fine, but the C2 and C3's results have a big error compared [5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaPjV.jpg)
[[image]][6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bGjn.jpg)
[with simulation results(Fig 4&5).]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JseLy.jpg)

[image]

Comment: [mcve] please, with the emphasis on _"minimal"_. :)